# Java reflection - checking method parameter type

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using this code in order to check a method parameters type and it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas what am I not doing right?

```
Class<?>[] parameter_types = m.getParameterTypes();
if (parameter_types[0].equals(Integer.class)) {
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

`m` is a method with integer type parameter:

```
public void m(int param);
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: can you please post the method signature of "m"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer` and `int` are different types. `Integer` is the reference type `java.lang.Integer`. `int` is a primitive type and has its own `Class` object.

```
if (parameter_types[0].equals(int.class)) {
```

Comment: had no clue int had attributes, always assumed that primitives didn't. Learnt something new today. I tip my hat to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   String parameter_types = m.getParameterClassName(1);
      if (parameter_types.equals(int.class)) {
      //DO SOMETHING
   }
```

For more information: [click!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html#getParameterClassName%28int%29)

Comment: beaten to it by 3 minutes I see. You deserve the upvote too.